Whitch metadata database objects I can delete in Airflow 2.8.2?
I got Airflow 2.8.2 installed with Docker.
I need clean Postgres database used with Airlow to free space on hard drive.
First of all this is my database memory usage:

As I know I can't just delete rows from tables.
So I found simple dag for clearing database:
from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import DagRun
from sqlalchemy.orm import load_onlysession = settings.Session()def remove_old_dag_runs():
    query = session.query(
            DagRun # specify of which resource metadata should be removed
        ).options(
            load_only(
                DagRun.execution_date # just get the execution date column
            )
        )
    query = query.filter(
            DagRun.execution_date < '2022-02-25 12:23:38.462662+00'
        )
    query.delete(synchronize_session=False)
    session.commit()remove_old_dag_runs_task = PythonOperator(
    task_id='remove_old_dag_runs',
    python_callable=remove_old_dag_runs,
    dag=dag
)

Also I found this code for DB cleaning.
But this code used with old Airflow version.
So which database object I can delete in Airflow 2.8.2?
I got this list of objects:
airflow.models list 1:
DagModel, DagRun, Log, XCom, SlaMiss, TaskInstance, Variable
airflow.models list 2:
TaskReschedule, TaskFail, RenderedTaskInstanceFields, ImportError

airflow.jobs list 1:
from airflow.jobs.base_job import BaseJob
airflow.jobs list 2:
from airflow.jobs.scheduler_job import SchedulerJob
from airflow.jobs.local_task_job import LocalTaskJob

P. S. I use this classes for cleaning DB:
DATABASE_OBJECTS = {
    'DagRun': {
        "airflow_db_model": DagRun # class
        , "age_check_column": DagRun.execution_date # column for date filter
        , "keep_last": True # keep last dag run (true / false)
        , "keep_last_filters": [DagRun.external_trigger.is_(False)] # additional filter
        , "keep_last_group_by": DagRun.dag_id
        , 'age_in_days': 14 # days to keep
    }
    , 'TaskInstance': {
        "airflow_db_model": TaskInstance
        , "age_check_column": TaskInstance.execution_date
        , "keep_last": False
        , "keep_last_filters": None
        , "keep_last_group_by": None
        , 'age_in_days': 14
    }
    , XCom.__name__: {
        "airflow_db_model": XCom
        , "age_check_column": XCom.execution_date
        , "keep_last": False
        , "keep_last_filters": None
        , "keep_last_group_by": None
        , 'age_in_days': 3
    }
    , 'TaskReschedule': {
        "airflow_db_model": TaskReschedule
        , "age_check_column": TaskReschedule.execution_date
        , "keep_last": False
        , "keep_last_filters": None
        , "keep_last_group_by": None
        , 'age_in_days': 14
    }
}

For DagRun I get this query:
delete
from    airflow.dag_run
where   execution_date not in (select max(execution_date) from dag_run where external_trigger = false group by dag_id)
        and execution_date <= current_date - interval '14 days'

Other classes keep filter by date only.

You can safely delete the rows from XCom table as they are used to pass information between tasks, for previous dag run you can get rid of this data.

Only XCom? What about another tables?

Please refer to this page for more details on which tables can be cleaned. https://www.astronomer.io/docs/learn/cleanup-dag-tutorial
